# Instant Search with keyup vuejs and laravel

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, keyup

I tried to build an instant search using vuejs and laravel 5.3 but somehow It wont work with no errors showing

Controller (fullcode https://pastebin.com/6mQ4eWTf) :

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $search = $request->search;
        $items = Staff::where('nama', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
        $response = [
            'pagination' => [
                'total'        => $items->total(),
                'per_page'     => $items->perPage(),
                'current_page' => $items->currentPage(),
                'last_page'    => $items->lastPage(),
                'from'         => $items->firstItem(),
                'to'           => $items->lastItem()
            ],
            'data'       => $items
        ];
```

staff.js method (fullcode https://pastebin.com/NDxzqsyp) :

```
methods: {
        getVueItems: function (page) {
            this.$http.get('/staffitems?page=' + page + '&search=' + this.search).then((response) => {
                this.$set('items', response.data.data.data);
                this.$set('pagination', response.data.pagination);
            });
            setTimeout(this.getVueItems, 5000);
        },
```

Blade (fullcode https://pastebin.com/6uDZRryE) :

```
<input v-on:keyup.enter="getVueItems" type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Cari..." v-model="search"/>
```

Routes :

```
Route::get('/staffcrud', 'StaffController@Crud');
Route::resource('/staffitems', 'StaffController');
```

The data correctly shown (tested by getting json response from /staffitems?page=1&search=jon with or without search value), but somehow when I do type words to search in input search column, nothing happened as soon as i finished typing, probably event handling in blade are wrong or my method in staff.js any solution for this?

Comment: I intent to search as soon as i done typing no need to press enter...

Comment: still not work... :( what is debounce?

Comment: Is the http call made?

Comment: yes i did have result for query all but not for search. updated question with full code.

Comment: Is this Vue 2 or 1?

Comment: Vue1 thats the problem...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that until you posted the full code. I'll let someone else answer; I didn't really work with Vue until 2.

Comment: I did wrote it version in tag, Its ok thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the debounce in your `mounted()` method:

```
mounted() {
    this.getVueItems = _.debounce(this.getVueItems, 5000); // i'm using lodash here.
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143024/discussion-on-answer-by-haiko-instant-search-with-keyup-vuejs-and-laravel).

Answer (score 0):

To build a really effective instant database search you should consider using pusher and laravel echo together with vuex

You can check out this out >>> [Ethiel Adiassa's Live Search Tutorial with laravel and pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/search-laravel-vue?utm_source=vuejstutorials.com)

Answer (score -1):

In your blade template use only:

```
v-on:keyup='vueGetItems'
```

Because your instant search is firing only on enter key up. I hope this will work or contact me to get full working code.